# Conventionally, how many amplitudes does a (harmonic) oscillator pass through in one full cycle?

Tags: waves, terminology, harmonic-oscillator

I don't know the typical scientific convention. My book says there are 4 amplitude. But no matter where I start the oscillator , the answer is at most 3.

[image]

Comment: What is your (your book's) definition of "amplitude"? Gert's answer correctly states that the motion for one full cycle will hit the two extremes of (position) amplitude exactly once. But if you allow for extremes of velocity to be called "amplitudes" as well, you can add two more points (the zero crossings).

Comment: The distance along the $t$ axis of your drawing from the first peak to the second peak is called the _period_ of the oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

The term 'amplitude' is often used somewhat ambiguously. The most rigorous definition is that amplitude is simply $|A|$ (the modulus of $A$). In your case (unmodulated wave or oscillation) there's only one amplitude.

But others count the number of peaks and troughs as 'amplitudes' like you are doing. You count only three but that's because Fig.14.2 only shows one and a half waves (oscillations), not two full ones. Add another half wave to the right side of your figure and you'd count 4 amplitudes for 2 waves, or 2 amplitudes per each full wave.

Comment: Who are these "others"?  I can not find any dictionary definition of "amplitude" that sounds like it refers to the relative maxima or minima of a periodic function.  The only definitions I can find that sound even vaguely physical or mathematical all mean the same as the $A$ in $A\cos(\omega t)$.